# Difference between ComponentDidUpdate and SetState callback function

Tags: javascript, react-native, callback, state

I've done some research about an error I got in my react native app

> Warning: An update (setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate) was scheduled from inside an update function. Update functions should be pure, with zero side-effects. Consider using componentDidUpdate or a callback..

I've done research but I still can't understand the difference between them. My theoretical idea is to remove an element from an array of objects, but when I use setState with a callback function I get the error. Can anyone point me in the right direction or show me an example of how I can use `componentDidUpdate`. The code example below works for now but I feel it could be improved on, and I believe that is why I'm getting my error

```js
  Delete_Task = (e) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const tasks = prevState.daily.filter(task => task.ID !== e);
      this.setState({daily: tasks});
    })
  }
```

Comment: When you use a function in setState you need to `return` the new state from the callback function, not call setState again inside the function

Comment: @charlietfl I changed it to ``return {tasks};`` but it  doesn't remove the element anymore.

Comment: What about the `daily` property? Also beware that if you have any other properties in the state you will lose them only returning `daily`

Comment: what about it, I'm setting a new const, how would I return it with the daily property

Comment: Try `return {daily:tasks}` or if you also have other properties `return {...prevState,daily:tasks}`

Comment: @charlietfl that seems to do the trick

Comment: Can you post as an answer so I can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the new state object instead of calling another setState inside the outer setState callback

change

```
this.setState({daily: tasks});
```

To

```
return {daily: tasks};
// OR 
return {...prevState, daily:tasks}
```